# Python AWS lambda function - DynamoDB to CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to write a Lambda function to index dynamodb table data into CloudSearch using Python. Is it possible to write the code inline and not create a separate deployment package for the same. I am completely new to AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to write the Lambda function inline since the AWS SDK for Python (boto3) is included in the Lambda environment.

Answer (score 0):

[He is the code you need to do that exact thing](https://gist.github.com/ryanfitz/8febe89a8208c810f98b).